# Google Sheets Extract Data from Table and make a row per data set

Tags: filter, google-sheets, pivot, extract

I'm stuck with Google Sheets.

Situation:
I have a data table with projects. Each project as a few attributes, most importantly including which team member has worked on the project this month.

Goal:
I need to convert the data to a new table that is built up differently. I need one row per project per active team member.

Sample data and goal:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QcNPsvHX8hBNUpCJiutof8yD8ukFYcCXM_pLNrQmDUs/edit?usp=sharing (can edit)

[image]
As you can see, SEO and Island now have two rows instead of one, as Jan AND Chris have worked on the projects this month.

Approach:
I tried FILTER, QUERY (with pivot) and thought about Scripting (basically its an iteration over the Matrix B3:E8...). However, I am not particularly skilled at Sheets and am very thankful for your help. Thanks a billion, guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a fairly standard way by using Textjoin to join together the corresponding column headers and other data for the non-blank cells, then separating it into rows then rows and columns with the Transpose and Split functions:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("¶",true,if(B3:E8="","",A3:A8&"|"&F3:F8&"|"&G3:G8&"|"&H3:H8&"|"&I3:I8&"|"&B2:E2)),"¶")),"|"))
```